# How to load JS scripts locally from a WordPress plugin instead of external CDN on AMP pages?

Tags: javascript

WordPress plugin - JS scripts are loaded from external sources

When using the AMP plugin on Wordpress, some js scripts are loaded from cdn and this slows down page loading.
Is it possible to get a local version as part of a plugin?

Comment: Download CDN source, change URL to use local URL. _But_ CDN is slow? Really? You live in Terorussia or something? CDN's are made to be extra fast.